# PhantomJS 5-min Wiki phantom.exit() oddity

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

So the example from the wiki has `phantom.exit()` in two places here. Why can't I just put `phantom.exit()` at the end of the script? It doesn't make too much sense to me.

```js
var page = require('webpage').create(),
t, address;

if (phantom.args.length === 0) {
    console.log('Usage: loadspeed.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(); //Why does this only work if "phantom.exit()" is here,
} else {
    t = Date.now();
    address = phantom.args[0];
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        } else {
            t = Date.now() - t;
            console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
        }
        phantom.exit(); //and here.
    });
}
// but not just a single one here?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `page.open` method is asynchronous, so the callback function you pass to it will run at some point in the future (when the resource referred to by `address` has finished loading).

If you put a call to `phantom.exit()` at the end of that script, PhantomJS will exit before the callback has had a chance to execute.